# Function that pulls data from backend database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The function is as following

ExecuteSQL('SELECT o.order_id,o.name,o.price from Orders as o where o.account_id = '+Request.parameter('account_id'));

The function is trying to extract the account_id from the url, what are some issues that can arise for this method? any better suggestions for getting account_id?

Comment: Does your solution work? Why do you think there would be issues with it? What is you definition of “better”?

Answer (score 0):

You are allowing SQL injection. Consider a hacker put `NULL OR 1 = 1`  as account_id. It will list everything out. Or `NULL; DROP TABLE your_table_name;`, `your_table_name` will be dropped

Comment: Thanks a lot, but can you please elaborate what it means by "it will list everything out"? How should I execute the function effectively then?